# Tracking custom events for more than 30 mins using Firebase events

Tags: android, ios, events, sdk, firebase-analytics

Is there any way I can check all the Firebase custom events that were fired by app, in last day or in last week using Firebase custom events. Currently, it shows me events that were fired 30 mins ago only.

Comment: Firebase consists of 18 products, and multiple of them have the concept of "events". Can you edit your question (and its tags) to clarify what Firebase product it is about?

Comment: I mean firebase custom events

Comment: Please read [Under what circumstances may I add “urgent” or other similar phrases to my question, in order to obtain faster answers?](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/326569) - the summary is that this is not an ideal way to address volunteers, and is probably counterproductive to obtaining answers. Please refrain from adding this to your questions.